# mvc async await link clicks wait till task finished

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await, jsonresult

I have a MVC website where I am trying to call a method with async. My code is like below:

**Views**

```
 <a href="#" class="submit-download" data-id="24589">Submit Download</a>

    $(document).on('click', '.submit-download', function (evt) {
        var submit_url = '/SubmitDownloads/24589; 

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: submit_url,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Item1)
                        location.reload();

            }
        });

    });
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> SubmitDownloads(int id)
    {
        var respository = new WorkflowRepository();
        var result = await respository.SubmitAsync(id);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Repository Method**

```
    //db service call which will take much longer time
    public async Task<Tuple<bool, string>> SubmitAsync(id)
    {
        //long running method here
         await Task.Delay(20000);
         return new Tuple<bool, string>(true, "done with " + id);

    }
```

When user clicks on the 'Submit Download' link in Views, it complete the entire function quickly as its supposed to do and page shows responsive like scrollable, menu shows fine. But when I click on any link in the page, it waits till the entire operation is finished (20 seconds) and then redirect to respective URL.

If I change the Task.Delay to 50 seconds, link click takes 50 seconds to redirect.

Can you please guide me what I am missing here?

Comment: What did you except to happen?

Answer (score 1):

> But when I click on any link in the page, it waits till the entire operation is finished (20 seconds) and then redirect to respective URL.

Asynchronous controller methods don't make the HTTP interaction async, just the interaction from the web server to the web application async.  The idea is that a high volume web server can free up threads to service other requests while long-running requests are doing their thing.

When you click on a link, the browser *needs* to wait for a response before, well, processing that response (displaying the page).  There's no way to display a page without waiting for that page to be sent from the web server.

Comment: is there any way I can put this in background? It feels like page is crashed but not showing any error message.

Comment: @sarojanand: If loading a page takes a long time then I imagine you'll want to correct whatever is causing that.  Perhaps the server-side code can spawn a separate thread to perform the long-running task, or perhaps the web application can queue the task information in a database and an entirely separate process (a Windows Service, for example) can monitor that database and perform the long-running tasks separately?  (That's generally what I'd do.)  Web page responses aren't a good place to put things that take a long time to happen.

Comment: David, I understand what you are saying. Service code is fine, its just it has to do a lot of I/O operations and then calculate, it takes 10-30 seconds based on data. So nothing much we can do to optimise it. That's why we are thinking to make our UI more responsive using Tasks.

Comment: @sarojanand: Using Tasks offloads the operations to an asynchronous context, but as you're seeing it doesn't necessarily make the UI more responsive.  Especially not in a web application where the UI *by design* needs to wait for the server to complete.  (Because the server is literally *responding with* the UI.)  The basic rule is to not perform long-running tasks in a web application request.  Offload them to something else, such as a separate thread or process.  By performing long-running tasks inline in a web application that forces the end user to wait for those tasks to complete.